# How to send a variable from index to controller in opencart

Tags: php

I want to set a variable in **index.php** and want to access that variable in any controller of open cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it we can achieve this by declaring a public variable in controller.php in system/engine/controller.php and then u can access this variable in any controller by simply doing

```
$this->variable_name = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a session variable.

`$_SESSION['your Variable'] = "variable value";`

this way you can set it.

You can get it by accessing.

`$var_value = $_SESSION['your Variable']`